# Newest loan per user for all users

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, greatest-n-per-group

// Edit:

All work fine with:

```
SELECT u.*,
    l.cod AS loans_cod,
    l.step AS loans_step
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN loans AS l
ON u.id = l.users_id
WHERE l.step < 12
    OR NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT l.id
            FROM loans
            WHERE l.users_id = u.id
        )
GROUP BY u.id
```

Now, I can select all user, and his last loan. Thanks, and I think my solution will help future users.

Comment: what column/values identifies the last loan of a user ?

Comment: I have the loan table, with every loan an user_id, all loans closed, has step 12, and the last not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the last loan, you could append something like this

```
ORDER BY l.date DESC GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: I have tried, and get all user with only one associated loans, It`s ok, but I need only the last one loan, not the first associated.

Comment: As I said to galador, all dates are posted in another table (history table), so, I can`t order from date or similar.

Comment: Ok, I have tested: ...WHERE l.step < 12 OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT l.id FROM loans WHERE l.users_id = u.id) GROUP BY u.id and it`s work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.*,
       l.cod  AS loans_cod,
       l.step AS loans_step
FROM   users AS u
       LEFT JOIN loans AS l
         ON u.id = l.users_id
WHERE  u.id != :id  
  AND  l.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(l.timestamp)
                      FROM loans AS l2
                      WHERE l2.users_id = l.users_id)
```

Where `timestamp` is a column on your table that indicates when the loan was created or otherwise gives you a time that you can compare to.

Comment: I thought this, but, all dates are posted in another table, so, I can`t use timestamp or similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.*, l.cod AS loans_cod, 
l.step AS loans_step 
FROM users AS u inner join
(
   select max(l.loan_id) as loan_id, l.users_id , l.cod, l.step
   from loans l 
   group by 
   l.users_id,l.cod,l.step
) as l
ON u.id = l.users_id  
WHERE u.id != :id
```

Note: Avoid doing `select *` it's a very bad practice. List all the columns you need only.

Comment: The question asks for the last loan *per user*

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that will give you only the user who's loan is most recent, not all the users and their lasts loan

Comment: OP wants all users but one loan per user so its not even close you need to group by with a having clause

Comment: @All, yes, Martin already pointed that out. I misunderstood the question. I believe I fixed it. If I didn't, downvote away!

Comment: You are calculating `MAX` but not using it anywhere?

Comment: @MartinSmith the inner join is already using max(loan_id). I don't see why another max. I'm just joining to the user_id on the outer select. I assume l.cod & l.step would be the same for different loan_ids. By their name, I judge they should be.

Comment: @Icarus - You are calculating `MAX` and giving it an alias `loan_id` but it never gets used anywhere.

Comment: @MartinSmith I know, as I was writing the inner select I thought I was going to need it for my join so I aliased it. Then I realized that assuming same values for l.step and l.cod for different loan_ids, the grouping would have returned unique records for max loan id and user id so I didn't need it but left it there. It shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hello, not ok, so far. It give-me all users, and all loans associated with a user.